# How to use a value from a cell in a function in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to calculate the number of accidents 1000 drivers will have in a year with the probability of a driver getting into an accident being 1%.

I received help in reaching the below code:

```
Public Function AccidentGenerator(N As Long) As Long
Application.Volatile
Dim i As Long
Randomize
For i = 1 To N
    AccidentGenerator = AccidentGenerator + Int(Rnd() + 0.01)

Next i
End Function
```

However, I would like to be able to change the probability within my workbook - i.e. make the 0.01 in the code above reference a cell inside my workbook. Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Another go:

```
Public Function AccidentGenerator(N As Long, epsilon As Double) As Long
    Application.Volatile
    Dim i As Long
    Randomize
    For i = 1 To N
        AccidentGenerator = AccidentGenerator + Int(Rnd() + epsilon)
    Next i
End Function
```

Like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `Evaluate()` function, or its alternate syntax `[]`.

For example, if cell A1 contains the value 0.01:

```
Debug.Print Evaluate("A1") ' prints 0.01
Debug.Print [A1]           ' also prints 0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

Or point at a cell as follows:

```
Public Function AccidentGenerator(ByVal N As Long) As Long
Application.Volatile
Dim i As Long
Randomize
For i = 1 To N
    AccidentGenerator = AccidentGenerator + Int(Rnd() + Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"))
Next i
End Function
```

The cell A1 in sheet1 referenced by

```
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

would contain the 0.01. You can obviously change the cell/worksheet/value in cell.